# missing symbolic link

Tags: unix, filesystems, symbolic-link

I have two directories with multiple directories and files
Lets say that directory A has some symbolic links to other directories and files and directory B is missing them. What can I do to copy those missing links to directory B recursively
I am using unix

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for link in `find /path/to/A -type l`; do cp $link /path/to/B; done
```